# Facebook Graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Have to get Facebook user's date of birth using access key. My client provide list of facebook user id and access key for sample test. using that access key can get wall information for that users which made as public. But am not get users date of birth. Is there any way to get users date of birth

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're asking for the `user_birthday`, or that information won't be returned. Note that if users don't show their birthday on their profiles you might not get that regardless.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. my url is $url = https://graph.facebook.com/" . $id . "?limit=100&access_token=$atoken. In this $id facebook user id is passing. Is this how i need to make a request for user_birthday. can you guide me?